# Porting several dependent C++ makefile projects into MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I have several projects which depend on each other. For example, when I install them I do this:

Project1:
/configure & make & make install

Project2: 
/configure & make & make install

Such that "Project2" depends on some libraries of "Project1". I want to create an MSVC project for Project2, and start working with it, and changing it (and compiling it inside). How can I do this? 
Also, how different is this to be done in linux with Eclips (when you don't have admin permission and can't do 'make install')?

Comment: In Linux you can always install to your `~/` directory without admin permissions.

Comment: I think when you do 'make install' it automatically installs it somewhere in /bin or places like that. How can I install at '~/'? Should I set some settings for 'make install'?

Comment: I don't know th structure of your Makefiles, but generally there is some variable like `PREFIX`, that has default value, but can be overridden via environment variable. For example: `PREFIX=~/ make install`

Comment: FYI: take a look at CMake and these tools: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake#Basic_CMakeLists.txt_from-scratch-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create project dependence in Visual Studio.

> To assign dependencies to projects
>
> In Solution Explorer, select a project.
>
> On the Project menu, choose Project Dependencies.
>
> The Project Dependencies dialog box opens.
>
> On the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down
>   menu.
>
> In the Depends on field, select the check box of any other project
>   that must build before this project does.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is your usual clickfest, but you can define project dependencies.

Define one project per module, then go to the solution properties tab and, for each project, select the checkboxes that inform the IDE that this project depends on a set of other projects.

The IDE will then sort and build them in the appropriate order.